# Is there a way to close only the word doc being used by win32com object, wihout impacting other open docs?

Tags: python, ms-word, win32com

I am initializing a word application object using:

```
import win32com.client as win32  
wordapp = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
```

Now after making some changes, I am closing the doc and killing the object.

```
doc.Close()
wordapp.quit()
```

Now on quitting all my word docs are being closed. Is there a way to only close the doc used by win32com and leave all other open docs untouched?

If i don't quit the object on using the application the second time lot of different errors are cropping up.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Python, but in the languages I do use it's necessary to "set" the Word.Application object to Nothing / null in order to "release" it. Does Python have something like that? If yes, use that instead of wordapp.quit.

Comment: OK..let me check it out. I will let you know if I find something.

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this yet?

Comment: I did some simple testing and if you use:  word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")

Comment: Sorry ignore the above comment, I had to walk away from PC. I did some simple testing and if you use:  `word = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Word.Application")` and then `word.Visible = False` that will also hide any existing word documents that you have open. They will all minimize. If you don't use this then the document you are editing will open, so this is needed if you want to hide it. Is there a way to just hide the document you are working with and not existing documents that are open?

Answer (score 0):

This bit works for me:

```
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.Save
    wordapp.ActiveDocument.Close()
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but I see it has been viewed more than 2000 times - so it is worth referring to:
When you use the 'Dispatch' function - python checks if there is Word software (in this case) open; If not - he opens a new one, then - he joins you to the one that is already open. Then when you close 'your' word, you are actually closing the first word.
Therefore, you just need to use the DispatchEx function - which creates a new instance of the application, anyway. this is how it is done:

```
from win32com import client as wc
word = wc.DispatchEx('Word.Application')
```